# htaccess redirect mass crazy url to one urls

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

dear .. i have tried some solution but not work cause i'm dont know much of htaccess
i have issue with my php script that make google crawl my web in wrong url:

```
http://www.xaluan.com/modules.php?name=Horoscopes&file=detail&url=/news/thu-gian/trac-nghiem/2011/03/163906-thu-bay-cua-ban/modules.php%25253fname=News&file=categories&op=newindex&catid=2
```

correct urls only look similar like this:

```
http://www.xaluan.com/modules.php?name=Horoscopes&file=detail&url=/news/thu-gian/trac-nghiem/2011/03/163906-thu-bay-cua-ban/
```

it add one more time to urls this link: 
modules.php%25253fname=News&file=categories&op=newindex&catid=2
.. ect

but i have fix this issue by remove all those sripts
the other issue about google they come back and comback gain tried to crawl the link not exit ..
so i would like
redirect all those url ( have var: detail ) to one url

here my one

```
RedirectMatch ^/(.*)detail(.*)$ http://www.xaluan.com/toolbar/
```

but it nerver work ??
please help to corect

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^.*detail.*$  http://www.xaluan.com/toolbar/ [L,R=302]
```

Comment: sorry but your fix will be redirect all similar url like that.
I just need redirect which url has "detail" on it.. to correct one url only.
thanks for any solution

Comment: U want to redirect all urls containing detail to new toobar url?

Comment: yes .. because google crawl those link .. then people keep come from search to that links ( but that pages removed ), and some time google recrawl them again .. I just dont want they see the no meaning 404 page .